# Prove that the function $I:(X,d^*)\to(R,d)$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Let $X$ be the set of continuous functions $f:[a,b]\to R$. Let $d^*$ be the distance function on $X$ defined by $$d^*(f,g)=\int_{a}^{b}|f(t)-g(t)|dt$$ for $f,g\in X$. For each $f\in X$, set $$I(f)=\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt$$Prove that the function $I:(X,d^*)\to(R,d)$ is continuous.

---

Let $\epsilon>0$. Suppose that $X$ is the set of continuous functions. Let $f\in X$ and $c\in[a,b]$, there exists a $\delta(\epsilon/(b-a))$ such that $|t-c|\leq\delta(\epsilon/(b-a))$, then $|f(t)-f(c)|\leq\epsilon/(b-a)$. To show $I$ is continuous, we do 
            $$d^*(f(t),f(c))=\left|\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt-\int_{a}^{b}f(c)dt\right|\leq\int_{a}^{b}\left|f(t)-f(c)\right|dt\leq\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}=\epsilon$$ Hence, $I$ is continuous.

---

Can someone check this solution valid or not? I have hard time to understand $I:(X,d^*)\to(R,d)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show that $|I(f)-I(g)|$ is small if $f$ is close to $g$ in terms of the metric $d^*$. This is just the triangle inequality for integrals.

In detail, let $\epsilon >0$ and let $f \in X$. We want to show continuity at $f$. Choose $\delta =\epsilon$. If $g \in X$ and $d^*(g,f)<\delta$, then $$|I(g)-I(f)|=\left|\int_a^b (g(t)-f(t))dt\right|\leq \int_a^b |g(t)-f(t)|dt=d^*(g,f)<\delta =\epsilon.$$

Comment: why $|I(f)-I(g)|$?

Comment: When you want to show a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous at $x_0$, you need to estimate the distance between $f(x)$ and $f(x_0)$, in terms of the distance function on $Y$. In this case, that is just the reals with absolute value.

Comment: I understand I need absolute value, but I am confusing why we need to show $|I(f)-I(g)|$. If so, we have $|\int f-\int g|\leq\int|f-f(c)|+\int|f(c)-g(c)|+\int|g(c)-g||$, how do we deal with $\int|f(c)-g(c)|$

Comment: What is $c$? $I$ maps a space of functions to the real numbers. You have to show $I$ is continuous at each point, but points in your $X$ are functions.

Comment: for any $f,g\in X$, pick $\delta=\epsilon/(b-a)$ such that $|f-g|<\delta$, then $|\int f-\int g|<\int|f-g|<\epsilon$

Comment: $|f-g|<\delta$ doesn't make any real sense here. Should I include full details in my answer?

Comment: Please! I am still confusing.

Comment: Can I show $I$ is Lipschitz? It seems like $C=1$, then I am done.

Comment: Right! I didn't know if you knew that term